# Any way to use the onboard system beep (a.k.a. PC speaker) as Windows audio device?

Tags: windows, audio, driver, beep, speaker

We have a lot of older Touch-PC systems that only need to show our web visualization. These systems do not have any audio devices onboard, there's just the good old plain PC speaker that can output beeps.

Now we need to trigger a warning beep signal from within the web application. After some research it seems that there's no way to output a system beep from within the HTML5 application, the only way would be via window.AudioContext or window.webkitAudioContext resp.

I know how to output sounds from Javascript, the question is: is there any way to make the onboard piezo PC speaker a windows audio device? It does not matter how terrible it sounds as I just need to output a pretty standard warning beep only. Have you heard of any drivers that can achieve that?